# Blank form appears after submitting in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, firewall

I have an application that has multiple tabs to submit a form. However, users are getting a blank form after hitting submit, and are not redirected to the confirmation page. This is odd because some applications are submitting fine, while others are not storing the data from fields to the database. My first guess was that it was a firewall issue. I am using a post method for submit. Another note, this is something that is occurring on our production server but not on our local development environment.

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Applicant")]
        public IActionResult Application(ApplicationViewModel model)
        {

            var saved = false;
            model = _applicantManager.RebuildApplicationViewModel(model);



            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                saved = _applicantManager.SubmitApplication(model, CurrentUser.UserName);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }


            return View(model);
        }
```

Form (Rather large so shortened for simplicity):

```
 @Html.ValidationSummary(excludePropertyErrors: false, message: "", htmlAttributes: new { @style = "color:red" })

        <ul class="wdn_tabs">
            <li><a href="#personalTab" class="inactiveLink">Personal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#academicTab" class="inactiveLink">Academic</a></li>
            <li><a href="#questionsTab" class="inactiveLink">Questions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#availabilityTab" class="inactiveLink">Availability &amp; Reference</a></li>
        </ul>
        @using (Html.BeginForm(actionName: "Application", controllerName: "Applicant", method: FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="wdn_tabs_content">
                <div id="personalTab">
                    <h4>Personal Information</h4>
                    <div style="color:red"><strong>All fields are required.</strong></div>
                    <div class="tabBody">

                        <div class="inputGroup spacer">
                            <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.PersonalInfo.FirstName)</strong>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PersonalInfo.FirstName)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PersonalInfo.FirstName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="inputGroup spacer">
                            <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.PersonalInfo.LastName)</strong>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PersonalInfo.LastName)
                            <input type="text" asp-for="PersonalInfo.LastName" />
                        </div>

                       ..........................other fields..........................
                    </div>             


                    <div class="tabFooter">
                        <a href="#questionsTab" class="wdn-button wdn-button-brand">Back</a>
                        <button type="submit" class="wdn-button wdn-button-complement">Submit</button>
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
        }
```

Comment: try testing with a single quote in one of the fields and see if it crashes

Comment: No problem there, seems to take a single quote just fine.

Comment: What do you see in the network tab of your development tools? Do you see that the redirect is happening as expected? Do you maybe see a blank response being sent in response to the following of that redirect? Turn on "preserve logs" to make sure you capture logs before and after the redirect (if one is happening)

Comment: @Jacob No problem there with the response, it seems to contain all the values.

Comment: You're seeing a redirect response, a request to the new URL, and the HTML coming back from the second response? If so, then maybe the HTML is there but you can't see anything (style issues, maybe?)